# Instantiate a class with an unknown name in php?

Tags: php, class, abstract-class, instantiation

I'm using an abstract `Page` class to create a template system in PHP. Each page on my website is its own class extending the `Page` class. Since one cannot instantiate an abstract class like `$page = new Page();` I can't figure out how to instantiate the extending-page's class without knowing that page's class name.

Is it possible to instantiate a class that extends an abstract class if I only know the name of the abstract class at run time? If so, how would I go about doing that?

---

Pseudocode of the Page class:

```
<?php    
abstract class Page{
    private $request = null;
    private $usr;
    function __construct($request){
        echo 'in the abstract';
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->usr = $GLOBALS['USER'];
    }

    //Return string containing the page's title. 
    abstract function getTitle();

    //Page specific content for the <head> section.
    abstract function customHead();

    //Return nothing; print out the page. 
    abstract function getContent();
}?>
```

The index page that loads everything would have code like this:

```
require_once('awebpage.php');
$page = new Page($request);
/* Call getTitle, customHead, getContent, etc */
```

The individual pages would look like:

```
class SomeArbitraryPage extends Page{
    function __construct($request){
        echo 'in the page';
    }

    function getTitle(){
        echo 'A page title!';
    }

    function customHead(){
        ?>
            <!-- include styles and scripts -->
        <?php 
    }
    function getContent(){
        echo '<h1>Hello world!</h1>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `get_parent_class` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php

Comment: That's getting the parent. I know the parent class—Page—but I don't know the child class name.

Comment: can you provide some pseudo code? not exactly following for some reason

Comment: You could look at the `Factory Method` pattern. So you'd end up with something like `Page::create('page1')` which returns a valid instance of the class that handles `Page1` of your website. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: It will be hard to do that. May be you can change your architecture. Give us more info: why you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate a class without knowing it's name. As being said above, you can use variable as a class/function name. You could have a list of all Page children with:

```
abstract class Page {
        public static function me()
        {
            return get_called_class();
        }
    }

class Anonym extends Page {

}

$classes = get_declared_classes();
$children = array();
$parent = new ReflectionClass('Page');

foreach ($classes AS $class)
{
    $current = new ReflectionClass($class);
    if ($current->isSubclassOf($parent))
    {
        $children[] = $current;
    }
}

print_r($children);
```

and get following output

```
Array ( [0] => ReflectionClass Object ( [name] => Anonym ) )
```

But then again, if you don't know the name, you won't know the index either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable for the function/class names:

```
class YourExtendedClass {
    public function example(){
        echo 1;
    }
}

$class = 'YourExtendedClass';
$t = new $class();
$t->example();
```